# Renaming debian package

Tags: debian, apt, packages

I'm trying to build a customized version of a nginx package for Debian/Ubuntu which had a different set of modules opposed to the default version.

What would be the fastest way to modify the  debian/ structure (and which files) if I'd want to rename the package from 'nginx' to 'my-nginx' for example?

I've got the source deb package unpacked and which files I'd need to modify in nginx-1.4.5/debian/ directory (holding the control, rules.. files) have buildpackage generate my-nginx-1.4.5.deb package instead of nginx-1.4.6.deb package.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes,edit the "spec" file (debian equivalent) so once I build the packages they ahow as my-nginx-1.4.6.deb for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way: modify file `debian/control` file so that you have the line:

```
Package: my-nginx
```

instead of just `nginx`.